# Using useEffect with React-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a problem. As I understood hook useEffect doen't run.
I have action that should take data from server.

```
export const getProducts = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getProductsStarted());

        fetch('https://shopserver.firebaseapp.com/get-products')
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(getProductsSuccess(res.json()));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(getProductsFailure(err.message));
            });
    }
}

const getProductsSuccess = todo => ({
    type: "ADD_TODO_SUCCESS",
    payload: {
        ...todo
    }
});

const getProductsStarted = () => ({
    type: "ADD_TODO_STARTED"
});

const getProductsFailure = error => ({
    type: "ADD_TODO_FAILURE",
    payload: {
        error
    }
});
```

I have a reducer.

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    products: [],
    error: null
}

export const ProductReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_TODO_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: null,
                todos: [...state.products, action.payload.products]
            }
        case "ADD_TODO_STARTED":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case "ADD_TODO_FAILURE":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload.error
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

And I have a Component where I want to render a result.

```
import React from 'react';
import { CardItem } from "./cardItem";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getProducts } from '../Redux/Actions/productAction'

export const ProductCard = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        console.log('111111')
    })

    const data = useSelector(state => state.ProductReducer.products);

    return (
        <div>
            {data.map( element =>
                CardItem (element)
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

After rendering page nothing happens. ReduxDevTools shows that there was no send actions. Please, help me to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be calling your async action like this :

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

[...]

export const ProductCard = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
      // I guess getProducts is an async redux action using redux-thunk
      dispatch(getProducts());
      console.log('111111')
  }, []);

  [...]

}
```

I assume you want to load products only when component is born, so I pass an empty array as second argument for useEffect (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I see an action ans state changes in reduxDevTools. But now I have an error Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. I think it's because on first render state.ProductReducer.products is empty.